# Cannot get Java Selenium in headless mode

Tags: java, selenium

I've searched around for awhile now and it seems like i just need to add chrome options to get selenium to go into headless mode. I am quite new and i maybe missing something but i've tried the adding the code below into my scripts in to various areas and it doesn't seem to work.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("window-size=1400,800");
options.addArguments("headless");
```

I've tried the following

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class TestPlan {

    private static final WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    @BeforeSuite
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Utils.CHROME_DRIVER_LOCATION);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("window-size=1400,800");
        options.addArguments("headless");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    }
    
    @Test(testName = "Login Page")
    public static void wikiLogin() {
        driver.get(Utils.WIKI_LOGIN_URL);
        WikiLogin wikilogin = new WikiLogin(driver);
        wikilogin.loginButton();
    }
```

and

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class TestPlan {

    private static final WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    @BeforeSuite
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Utils.CHROME_DRIVER_LOCATION);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    }

    @Test(testName = "Login Page")
    public static void wikiLogin() {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("window-size=1400,800");
        options.addArguments("headless");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get(Utils.WIKI_LOGIN_URL);
        WikiLogin wikilogin = new WikiLogin(driver);
        wikilogin.loginButton();
    }

With no success. Would appreciate some help. Thanks!
```

Comment: Try switching to  private static final WebDriver driver ; and then driver = new ChromeDriver(options) to access the private variable inside the functions.

Comment: driver.manage().window().fullscreen(); did you try this function ?